# Cannot Use and Retrieve Data from MySQL Database

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, json

I am trying to retrieve a list of schools from my database according to some specific parameters provided by the user. I have a lot of code, but I cannot locate my error and need some help. I have spent over 6 hours researching and trying to fix this. I cannot seem to fix it. I would appreciate any help.

This is an android app connecting to a MySQL database btw.

Here is my code for initiating the search when the button is clicked:

```
btnGetSchool.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String city = inputCity.getText().toString();
                String school = inputSchoolName.getText().toString();
                String state = chooseState.getSelectedItem().toString();
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                JSONObject json = userFunction.getSchool(school, state, city);



                try {
                    schoolText.setText(json.getString(""));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }


        });
```

Here is my UserFunctions.java code:

```
public JSONObject getSchool(String school, String state, String city) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("school", school));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("state", state));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", city));


        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(getSchoolURL, params);
        return json;
    }
```

My JSON Parser:

```
package com.fbla.sap;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Lastly, my PHP code for actually searching for the schools. I feel like the error might originate here because I am very new to PHP and don't completely understand it:

```
public function schoolSearch($school, $state, $city){

        $schsearch=mysql_query("
                SELECT `sch_name`, `sch_id`,sch_state`,`sch_city`
                FROM `schools`
                WHERE (`sch_name`=$school) AND (`sch_state`=$state) AND (`sch_city`=$city)
            ");
            /**$searchresult=array();-
            while($schresult=mysql_fetch_array($schsearch)) {

                array_push($searchresult, $schresult['sch_id']."=>".$schresult['sch_name']);


            }**/

            return mysql_fetch_array($schresult);

            /**if (count($searchresult) > 0) {
                return $searchresult;
            } else {
                return false;
            }**/


    }
```

Just to sum things up I will add my error:

```
02-01 23:32:03.260: E/AndroidRuntime(12803): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-01 23:32:03.260: E/AndroidRuntime(12803): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-01 23:32:03.260: E/AndroidRuntime(12803):    at com.fbla.sap.CreateAccFragment$2.onClick(CreateAccFragment.java:148)
02-01 23:32:03.260: E/AndroidRuntime(12803):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
02-01 23:32:03.260: E/AndroidRuntime(12803):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18784)
02-01 23:32:03.260: E/AndroidRuntime(12803):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-01 23:32:03.260: E/AndroidRuntime(12803):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-01 23:32:03.260: E/AndroidRuntime(12803):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-01 23:32:03.260: E/AndroidRuntime(12803):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5450)
02-01 23:32:03.260: E/AndroidRuntime(12803):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 23:32:03.260: E/AndroidRuntime(12803):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-01 23:32:03.260: E/AndroidRuntime(12803):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
02-01 23:32:03.260: E/AndroidRuntime(12803):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
02-01 23:32:03.260: E/AndroidRuntime(12803):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Missing opening backtick in `sch_state` in your SQL query.

Comment: There is so much wrong with this question. You've dumped a huge amount of code on us, and it's not even complete. You're expecting us to find an unspecified error without the benefit of any debugging you may have done. You have to narrow the problem down. Start at the PHP end, debug that and make sure it works properly. Then move up. Learn some proper debugging skills.

Comment: Any exceptions given by the PHP code fragment will likely give vastly more useful information. I'd suggest breaking the problem down, starting with the PHP block.

Comment: See the problem is, I don't know what the hell I am doing. I have done hours and hours of debugging, but to no avail. I jumped right into this, so I don't necessarily know how to fix some of these things.

Answer (score 0):

change

`return mysql_fetch_array($schresult);`

to

`return mysql_fetch_array($schsearch);`